# Как реализовать функционал кнопки +/- на калькуляторе

Tags: javascript

Пишу для опыта калькулятор на чистом js, не могу реализовать функционал кнопки +/-, которая добавляет перед введенным числом + или -, подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать.

У меня введенные данные попадают в переменные

```
let a = '';
let b = '';
let sign = '';
```

Все кнопки обернуты в блоке с классом .buttons, сама кнопка сверстана так

```
<div class="btn plus-minus bg-grey">+/-</div>
```

Основной функционал прописан так:

```
const digit = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '.']

document.querySelector('.buttons').onclick = (event) => {
if(!event.target.classList.contains('btn')) return;

if(event.target.classList.contains('ac')) return;

out.textContent = '';

const key = event.target.textContent;

if (digit.includes(key)) {
    if (b === '' && sign === '') {
    a += key;
    out.textContent = a
    } else if (a !== '' && b !== '' && finish) {
        b = key;
        finish = false;
        out.textContent = b;
    } else {
        b += key;
        out.textContent = b;
    }
    console.log(a, b, sign)
    return
 }
}
```

Пытаюсь вот так добавить символ перед введенным числом после нажания кнопки плюс/минус, в консоль выводится результат, но на калькуляторе самом остается пустая строка. Не могу разобраться почему :(

```
document.querySelector('.plus-minus').onclick = () => {
    a = a * -1
    out.textContent = a
    console.log(a)
    return
}
```

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Добавьте в ваш вопрос код к которомы вы пришли чтобы было легче вам помочь

Comment: Добавил код, как основной функционал прописал, и как пытаюсь сделать кнопку "плюс/минус". Не получается вывести результат в калькуляторе, т.е. в консоль выводит числа, но в самом калькуляторе пустая строка остается. Не могу разобраться почему :(

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

сделайте так, достаньте значение которое у вас на экране и на нажатие кнопки сделайте умножение на -1

Comment: Пожалуйста старайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы и прикладывать минимальный воспроизводимый (если можно) код

Comment: Спасибо, я так пытаюсь сделать, но не могу вернуть это значение в сам калькулятор. В консоли при клике на кнопку выводится результат как надо, но в самом калькуляторе пусто.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gquaiuj-VpU

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> document.querySelector('.plus-minus').onclick = () => {
>  a = a * -1
>  out.textContent = a
>  console.log(a)
>  return
> }
> ```

Так много вопросов и так мало ответов..
Что такое `a`? `.textContent` вернёт строку.. Зачем `return`?

---

Я бы реализовал так.

```js
const result = document.querySelector('#result'),
      plusMinus = document.querySelector('#plus-minus');
      
plusMinus.addEventListener('click', function() {
  result.value = +result.value * -1; // result.value - вернёт строку, конвертнём его в число дописав вначале "+", потом умножим на -1, что позволит "инвертировать" число.
});
```

```html
<input id="result" type="number" value="123"> <input id="plus-minus" type="button" value="±">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//нажата кнопка смены знака (+/-)
    function plusMin() {
       a = -1 * a; 
    }
    out.textContent = a;
    document.querySelector('.plus-minus').onclick = plusMin;
    console.log(a);
```

У Вас ошибка в том, что Вы пытаетесь записать результат и вывести его на экран калькулятора внутри функции.

```
document.querySelector('.plus-minus').onclick = () => {
        a = a * -1;
}
out.textContent = a;
//Вот так уже Ваша стрелочная функция будет работать.
```

Выше я привела пример обычной функции, так как она проще для понимания, если Вы учитесь.

Есть ещё проще вариант))))

Вы уже повесили обработчик событий на все кнопки :)

```
document.querySelector('.buttons').onclick
```

Смотрим далее:

```
if(!event.target.classList.contains('btn')) return;
//Это условие Вашей стрелочной функции, где написано, 
//что если ни одна из кнопок не нажата, 
//то возвращается пустое значение out.textContent = '';

if(event.target.classList.contains('ac')) return;
//Тут пустое значение возвращается если нажата кнопка очистки экрана.

out.textContent = ''; //Пустое значение, которое возвращается функциями.
```

Отсюда можно "плясать" дальше.

```
document.querySelector('.buttons').onclick = (event) => {
//когда нажата не кнопка, а промежуток между кнопками
if(!event.target.classList.contains('btn'))
return;
//нажата кнопка AC
if(event.target.classList.contains('ac'))
return;

out.textContent = '';

if(event.target.classList.contains('plus-minus')) {
    a = -1 * a; //Если нажата кнопка с классом plus-minus, то выполняется условие.
} else if(event.target.classList.contains('percent')) {
    a = a / 100; //Более чем уверена, что реализация процента калькулятора тоже пригодится :)
}

out.textContent = a; //Запись и вывод результата на экран.

//получаю нажатую кнопку
const key = event.target.textContent;
```

Вообще можно найти много способов реализации, главное понимать, что делаешь и как это всё работает.

Успехов :)

Answer (score 0):

В конкретно Вашем случае,если я правильно воспроизвел код ниже, срабатывают 2 события `onclick`, т.е. Вы забыли про всплытие событий, (**и никто из отвечающих на это не указал**) Хорошо советовать другой код, но лучше указать причину почему не работает этот.

У Вас отрабатывают 2 обработчика, первый на самой кнопке, второй на блоке кнопок. Поэтому вывод происходит, но потом затирается общим обработчиком,строкой `out.textContent = ''`, которую я закоментировал и все заработало:

```js
const out = document.querySelector('#out')
const digit = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '.']

let a = 1;
let b = '';

document.querySelector('.buttons').onclick = (event) => {
  if(!event.target.classList.contains('btn')) return;
  if(event.target.classList.contains('ac')) return;

  //out.textContent = '';  // <---------------------------- убрано

  const key = event.target.textContent;

  if (digit.includes(key)) {
      if (b === '' && sign === '') {
      a += key;
      out.textContent = a
      } else if (a !== '' && b !== '' && finish) {
          b = key;
          finish = false;
          out.textContent = b;
      } else {
          b += key;
          out.textContent = b;
      }
      console.log(a, b, sign)
      return
   }
   console.log('сработал второй обработчик')
}

document.querySelector('.plus-minus').onclick = () => {
  a = a * -1
  out.textContent = a
  console.log(a)
  console.log('сработал первый обработчик')
  return
}

out.textContent = a
```

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 0 5px; 
}
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
<div class="buttons">
  <div class="btn plus-minus bg-grey">+/-</div>
</div>
```

Кстати, если бы использовался **addEventListener**, то можно было бы предотвратить всплытие через третий аргумент — логическое значение (true/false), определяющее следует ли отправить событие дальше ("всплывание") или нужно закрыть это событие.

Что касается самой функции обработчика я бы сократил ее тело до `out.textContent =  a *= -1`

```js
let a = 1
const out = document.querySelector('#out')
out.textContent = a 

document.querySelector('.plus-minus').onclick = () => {
  out.textContent =  a *= -1 // сокращенная запись умножения
}
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
<button class="plus-minus">+/-</button>
```